# Consuming ColdFusion SOAP Service in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, soap, coldfusion, wsdl

We have a very old application that we are trying to consume a ColdFusion SOAP based web service from. When I query the WSDL, I can see that the getProductID Method (which requires a parameter of xProduct). When I create a new service reference from visual studio, it sees the Methods. I create the service reference and then when I attempt to use the method, it gives me a error that the method doesn't accept any parameters. Why is visual studio not picking up on this Parameter am I doing something wrong or can someone point in the right direction?

**Update:** I also verified using SOAPUI and www.soapclient.com that the parameters do come through correctly. I was able to test using both services and receive the correct response.

I also went the legacy route and added a Web Reference, and the web reference does seem to pick up the parameters. I would prefer not to use a Web Reference since this is old technology and some of it has been deprecated, and Microsoft only recommends using this if you are targeting 2.0.

[image]

```
<wsdl:message name="getProductIDResponse">
<wsdl:part name="getProductIDReturn" type="xsd:string"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getProductIDRequest">
<wsdl:part name="xProduct" type="xsd:string"/>
</wsdl:message>
```

Comment: Has the ColdFusion web service changed since you first attempted to consume it? I ask because there is a feature in ColdFusion when invoking services that tells the server to "refresh" the WSDL with any changes. [See this other post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16362528/consuming-coldfusion-webservice-web-service-operation-with-parameters-canno) Not sure how to accomplish that using .NET. Perhaps there is a way to clear the cache from the ColdFusion administrator.

Comment: @Miguel-F As far as I recall no changes have been made. We have an old .net app that we are re-writing and this is where I run into the issue. It works perfectly in the old code (other then it uses a web reference since it was .net 2.0)

Comment: @Miguel-F It is definitely a .net thing because when I test the service using soapclient.com it shows the correct parameters.

Comment: Just thought I would throw that out there. I'm afraid I can't be of much help on the .NET side. Please post back here when you figure it out.

Comment: is the attributes set to encoded or literal?

Comment: What version of WSDL is your ColdFusion web service using?

Comment: @BartSipes We are using 1.1.

Comment: look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10307549/1727357